# Moving Circular Floating Action Button up and down to avoid getting blocked by a snackbar

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

i am using Circular Floating Action Button with two subActionButtons
the onclick method on the subActionButton is to make a SnackBar
but the SnackBar cover the Main floating ActionButton and the SubButton too
do How Can i solve that

Comment: Use coordinate layout as parent layout.

Comment: Coordinate layout work with Floating action button

Comment: But I imported library for circular floating action button which contain subAction button whick make actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by
declare the coordinator layout in your java file
like 
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorlayout ;

coordinatorlayout = (CoordinatorLayout )findViewById(R.id.layout)

..... then in your snakBar the first parameter should be the the layout " coordinatorlayout "

Snackbar.make(coordinatorlayout , result, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) as parent layout. It makes sure that the FAP is animated up and down synchronously with the snackbar.

Comment: It dosen't work , it work with floating action button ... But I imported library for circular floating action button which contain subAction button whick make actions

Comment: @AbdalrhmanElsayed You should provide some code, so people can see what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide coordinate layout's behavior to the child view(in your case-circular floating action button), following post explains it in details [Overlap issue with snackbar](https://medium.com/@phaniraja/overlap-issue-with-snackbar-df49e25be407#.pbfaarz4d)